# Animated circle with easings on canvas based on dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So I have this fiddle made, and the objective is to point-out areas of the human body by selecting their respective areas in a dropdown list.

This is, currently, what I've made:

```js
let coords = {
    maleFirst: {
        hands: {
            left: {
                x: 100,
                y: 360
            },
            right: {
                x: 280,
                y: 360
            }
        },
        foot: {
            left: {
                x: 180,
                y: 590
            },
            right:{
                x: 210,
                y: 590
            }
        }
    },
    maleSecond: {
        hands: {
            left: {
                x: 365,
                y: 360
            },
            right: {
                x: 545,
                y: 360
            }
        },
        foot: {
            left: {
                x: 430,
                y: 590
            },
            right:{
                x: 480,
                y: 590
            }
        }
    }
}

let draw = (option) => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
      if (option === 'hands') {
     
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.hands.left.x, coords.maleFirst.hands.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.hands.right.x, coords.maleFirst.hands.right.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.hands.left.x, coords.maleSecond.hands.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.hands.right.x, coords.maleSecond.hands.right.y);

      }

      if (option === 'foot') {
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.foot.left.x, coords.maleFirst.foot.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.foot.right.x, coords.maleFirst.foot.right.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.foot.left.x, coords.maleSecond.foot.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.foot.right.x, coords.maleSecond.foot.right.y);
      }
     
    }
}




let coordsDraw = (ctx, x, y) => {
   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#01567f'; // color of fill

    ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

document.getElementById('options').addEventListener('change', function ()  {
  draw(this.value)

});
```

```css
#canvas {
   background-image:url('http://www.coloringsky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/How-to-Draw-Human-Body-Coloring-Pages.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:contain;
   background-position:center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="#">Select option</option>
  <option value="hands">hands</option>
  <option value="foot">foot</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
```

The idea that I'm aiming for is to have a more "stand-out" pointer, something among these lines:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

// set the context styles
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "gold";
ctx.fillStyle = "#888";

// variables used to draw & animate the ring
var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var ringX, ringY, ringRadius, ingCounter, ringCounterVelocity;
var cancelAnimationId;

// fill the canvas with a background color
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// tell handleMouseDown to handle all mousedown events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});

// set the ring variables and start the animation
function ring(x, y) {
    ringX = x;
    ringY = y;
    ringRadius = 0;
    ringCounter = 0;
    ringCounterVelocity = 4;

    cancelAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

// the animation loop
function animate() {

    // return if the animation is complete
    if (ringCounter > 200) {
        ringCounter = 0;
    }

    // otherwise request another animation loop
    cancelAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // ringCounter<100 means the ring is expanding
    // ringCounter>=100 means the ring is shrinking
    if (ringCounter < 100) {
        // expand the ring using easeInCubic easing
        ringRadius = easeInCubic(ringCounter, 0, 15, 100);
    } else {
        // shrink the ring using easeOutCubic easing
        ringRadius = easeOutCubic(ringCounter - 100, 15, -15, 100);
    }

    // draw the ring at the radius set using the easing functions
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ringX, ringY, ringRadius, 0, PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

    // increment the ringCounter for the next loop
    ringCounter += ringCounterVelocity;
}


//  Robert Penner's easing functions
//
//  https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js
//
//  now=elapsed time,
//  startValue=value at start of easing,
//  deltaValue=amount the value will change during the easing,
//  duration=total time for easing

function easeInCubic(now, startValue, deltaValue, duration) {
    return deltaValue * (now /= duration) * now * now + startValue;
}

function easeOutCubic(now, startValue, deltaValue, duration) {
    return deltaValue * ((now = now / duration - 1) * now * now + 1) + startValue;
}


// handle mousedown events
function handleMouseDown(e) {

    // tell the browser we'll handle this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // calc the mouse position
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // animate a ring at the mouse position
    cancelAnimationFrame(cancelAnimationId);
    ring(mouseX, mouseY);

}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click in the canvas to draw animated circle with easings.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

I'm having trouble in adapting the animation to what I'm looking for, as I end up having errors like these:

```js
let coords = {
    maleFirst: {
        hands: {
            left: {
                x: 100,
                y: 360
            },
            right: {
                x: 280,
                y: 360
            }
        },
        foot: {
            left: {
                x: 180,
                y: 590
            },
            right:{
                x: 210,
                y: 590
            }
        }
    },
    maleSecond: {
        hands: {
            left: {
                x: 365,
                y: 360
            },
            right: {
                x: 545,
                y: 360
            }
        },
        foot: {
            left: {
                x: 430,
                y: 590
            },
            right:{
                x: 480,
                y: 590
            }
        }
    }
}

let draw = (option) => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
      if (option === 'hands') {
     
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.hands.left.x, coords.maleFirst.hands.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.hands.right.x, coords.maleFirst.hands.right.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.hands.left.x, coords.maleSecond.hands.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.hands.right.x, coords.maleSecond.hands.right.y);

      }

      if (option === 'foot') {
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.foot.left.x, coords.maleFirst.foot.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleFirst.foot.right.x, coords.maleFirst.foot.right.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.foot.left.x, coords.maleSecond.foot.left.y);
        coordsDraw(ctx, coords.maleSecond.foot.right.x, coords.maleSecond.foot.right.y);
      }
     
    }
}



var ringRadius = 0, ringCounter = 0, ringCounterVelocity = 4;
let coordsDraw = (ctx, x, y) => {

    if (ringCounter > 200) {
        ringCounter = 0;
    }

    // otherwise request another animation loop
    cancelAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(coordsDraw(ctx, x, y));

    // ringCounter<100 means the ring is expanding
    // ringCounter>=100 means the ring is shrinking
    if (ringCounter < 100) {
        // expand the ring using easeInCubic easing
        ringRadius = easeInCubic(ringCounter, 0, 15, 100);
    } else {
        // shrink the ring using easeOutCubic easing
        ringRadius = easeOutCubic(ringCounter - 100, 15, -15, 100);
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#01567f'; // color of fill

    ctx.arc(x, y, ringRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    ringCounter += ringCounterVelocity;
}


function easeInCubic(now, startValue, deltaValue, duration) {
    return deltaValue * (now /= duration) * now * now + startValue;
}

function easeOutCubic(now, startValue, deltaValue, duration) {
    return deltaValue * ((now = now / duration - 1) * now * now + 1) + startValue;
}


document.getElementById('options').addEventListener('change', function ()  {
  draw(this.value)

});
```

```css
#canvas {
   background-image:url('http://www.coloringsky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/How-to-Draw-Human-Body-Coloring-Pages.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:contain;
   background-position:center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="#">Select option</option>
  <option value="hands">hands</option>
  <option value="foot">foot</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
```

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at coordsDraw (select.js:299)
```

Any help would be trully appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this (this example doesn't have animated rings but I show where you would place that code.

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<style>

    canvas {

    background-image:url('http://www.coloringsky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/How-to-Draw-Human-Body-Coloring-Pages.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    width: 100%;

    }

</style>
```

```
<select name="options" id="options">
    <option value="#">Select option</option>
    <option value="hands">hands</option>
    <option value="feet">feet</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<canvas width="650" height="650">

<script>

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var option = document.querySelector("select");


    var rings = [];
    var ringOffsetH = 110;
    var ringOffsetF = 155;

    animationLoop();


    //The ring constructor
    function Ring(x,y,r,v)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = r;
        this.visible = v;

        this.draw = function()
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();

        }

        this.animate= function()
        {
            //animation easing code goes here
        }
    };

    function animationLoop()
    {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop,canvas);


        //Loop through options tracking the currently selected one
        for(var o=0; o<option.length; o++)
        {
            var selectedOption = option.selectedIndex;

            switch(selectedOption)
            {
                case 1:
                    clearRings(rings);
                    for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
                    {
                        var ring = new Ring(165*n+ringOffsetH,350,10,true);//Here you could replace x,y with your coord getters instead of hardcoding as I have done
                        rings.push(ring);
                    }
                break;

                case 2:
                    clearRings(rings);
                    for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
                    {
                        var ring = new Ring(70*n+ringOffsetF,600,10,true);
                        rings.push(ring);
                    }
                break;

                default:
                clearRings(rings);
                console.log("nothing");
                break;
            }
        }

        //Loop through rings calling the rings animation function
        //if visible
        for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
        {
            var ring = rings[r];

            if(ring.visible)
            {
                ring.animate();
            }
        }


        render();
    };

    function clearRings(array)
    {
        this.array = array;

        array.length = 0;
    }

    function render()
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        //Loop through rings
       if(rings.length !== 0)
       {
        for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
        {
            //Assign the current ring to a temporary 
            //ring reference
            var ring = rings[r];

            //Draw the ring
            ring.draw();
        }
      }


    };



</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Now with animated rings"

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<style>

    canvas {

    background-image:url('http://www.coloringsky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/How-to-Draw-Human-Body-Coloring-Pages.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    width: 100%;

    }

</style>
```

```
<select name="options" id="options">
    <option value="#">Select option</option>
    <option value="hands">hands</option>
    <option value="feet">feet</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<canvas width="650" height="650">

<script>

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var option = document.querySelector("select");
    const EASING = .08;

    var rings = [];
    var ringOffsetH = 110;
    var ringOffsetF = 178;
    const RADIUS = 10;
    const MIN_RADIUS = 0;
    var shrinkRing = false;
    var growRing = false;


    animationLoop();


    //The ring constructor
    function Ring(n,x,y,r,v,vl)
    {
        this.name = n;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = r;
        this.visible = v;
        this.velocity = vl;

        this.draw = function()
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();

        }

        this.animate= function()
        {


            //animation easing code goes here
            if((this.radius > MIN_RADIUS && !growRing) 
              || (this.radius >= RADIUS && growRing))
            {
                growRing = false;
                shrinkRing = true;
                this.radius -= this.velocity * EASING;
            }
            if((this.radius < RADIUS && !shrinkRing) 
              || (this.radius < MIN_RADIUS && shrinkRing))
            {

                shrinkRing = false;
                growRing = true;

                this.radius += this.velocity * EASING;

            }

        }
    };

    function animationLoop()
    {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop,canvas);


        //Loop through options tracking the currently selected one
        for(var o=0; o<option.length; o++)
        {
            var selectedOption = option.selectedIndex;

            switch(selectedOption)
            {
                case 1:
                    if(rings.length !== 0)
                    {
                        for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
                        {
                            var tempRing = rings[r];

                            if(tempRing.name !== "hands")
                            {
                                clearRings(rings);

                                for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
                                {
                                    var ring = new Ring("hands",(165*n)+ringOffsetH,350,
                                    RADIUS,true,5);
                                    rings.push(ring);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
                        {
                            var ring = new Ring("hands",(165*n)+ringOffsetH,350,
                            RADIUS,true,5);
                            rings.push(ring);
                        }
                    }
                break;

                case 2:
                    if(rings.length !== 0)
                    {
                        for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
                        {
                            var tempRing = rings[r];

                            if(tempRing.name !== "feet")
                            {
                                clearRings(rings);

                                for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
                                {
                                    var ring = new Ring("feet",(30*n)+ringOffsetF,600,
                                    RADIUS,true,5);
                                    rings.push(ring);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
                        {
                            var ring = new Ring("feet",(30*n)+ringOffsetH,600,
                            RADIUS,true,5);
                            rings.push(ring);
                        }
                    }
                break;

                default:
                clearRings(rings);
                console.log("nothing");
                break;
            }
        }

        //Loop through rings calling the rings animation function
        //if visible
        for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
        {
            var ring = rings[r];

            if(ring.visible)
            {
                ring.animate();
            }
        }


        render();
    };

    function clearRings(array)
    {
        this.array = array;

        array.length = 0;
    }

    function render()
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        //Loop through rings
        if(rings.length !== 0)
        {
            for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
            {
                //Assign the current ring to a temporary 
                //ring reference
                var ring = rings[r];

                //Draw the ring
                ring.draw();
            }
        }


    };



</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset = 'utf-8'>

 <style>
 
  canvas {
  
  background-image:url('http://www.coloringsky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/How-to-Draw-Human-Body-Coloring-Pages.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
  width: 100%;
  
  }
 
 </style>



</head>

<body>


 <select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="#">Select option</option>
  <option value="hands">hands</option>
  <option value="feet">feet</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 
 <canvas width="650" height="650">

 <script>

  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  var option = document.querySelector("select");
  const EASING = .08;
  
  var rings = [];
  var ringOffsetH = 110;
  var ringOffsetF = 178;
  const RADIUS = 10;
  const MIN_RADIUS = 0;
  var shrinkRing = false;
  var growRing = false;
  
  
  animationLoop();
  
  
  //The ring constructor
  function Ring(n,x,y,r,v,vl)
  {
   this.name = n;
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.radius = r;
   this.visible = v;
   this.velocity = vl;
   
   this.draw = function()
   {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    
   }
   
   this.animate= function()
   {
    
    
    //animation easing code goes here
    if((this.radius > MIN_RADIUS && !growRing) || (this.radius >= RADIUS && growRing))
    {
     growRing = false;
     shrinkRing = true;
     this.radius -= this.velocity * EASING;
    }
    if((this.radius < RADIUS && !shrinkRing) || (this.radius < MIN_RADIUS && shrinkRing))
    {
  
     shrinkRing = false;
     growRing = true;
     
     this.radius += this.velocity * EASING;

    }
    
   }
  };
  
  function animationLoop()
  {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop,canvas);
   
   
   //Loop through options tracking the currently selected one
   for(var o=0; o<option.length; o++)
   {
    var selectedOption = option.selectedIndex;
   
    switch(selectedOption)
    {
     case 1:
      if(rings.length !== 0)
      {
       for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
       {
        var tempRing = rings[r];
        
        if(tempRing.name !== "hands")
        {
         clearRings(rings);
         
         for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
         {
          var ring = new Ring("hands",(165*n)+ringOffsetH,350,RADIUS,true,5);
          rings.push(ring);
         }
        }
       
       }
      }
      else
      {
       for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
       {
        var ring = new Ring("hands",(165*n)+ringOffsetH,350,RADIUS,true,5);
        rings.push(ring);
       }
      }
     break;
     
     case 2:
      if(rings.length !== 0)
      {
       for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
       {
        var tempRing = rings[r];
        
        if(tempRing.name !== "feet")
        {
         clearRings(rings);
         
         for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
         {
          var ring = new Ring("feet",(30*n)+ringOffsetF,600,RADIUS,true,5);
          rings.push(ring);
         }
        }
       
       }
      }
      else
      {
       for(var n=0; n<2; n++)
       {
        var ring = new Ring("feet",(30*n)+ringOffsetF,600,RADIUS,true,5);
        rings.push(ring);
       }
      }
     break;
     
     default:
     clearRings(rings);
     //console.log("nothing");
     break;
    }
   }
   
   //Loop through rings calling the rings animation function
   //if visible
   for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
   {
    var ring = rings[r];
    
    if(ring.visible)
    {
     ring.animate();
    }
   }
   
   
   render();
  };
  
  function clearRings(array)
  {
   this.array = array;
   
   array.length = 0;
  }
  
  function render()
  {
   context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   
   //Loop through rings
   if(rings.length !== 0)
   {
    for(var r=0; r<rings.length; r++)
    {
     //Assign the current ring to a temporary 
     //ring reference
     var ring = rings[r];
     
     //Draw the ring
     ring.draw();
    }
   }
    
   
  };



 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this is it.